# Why can't I add a controller to my roster?

Tags: xbox-one, halo-the-master-chief-collection

I've just bought the Halo Master Chief Collection, and I'm having certain issues trying to add another controller to the roster so I can play a co-op campaign. When I turn on the controller it appears that it's recognized by the roster and I can see an extra "press A to join" appear there, but when I actually press "A" on the second controller, it has no effect, and there's still only one player.

What's going on here?

Comment: Have you associated any profile with the controller?

Comment: @Eric I don't believe so. I'll try that later today.

Comment: Please let me know how it went. Here is a resource you might find helpful: https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/accessories/assign-controller-profile

Comment: @Eric I've tried associating a profile. It didn't have any effect. I'm going to try updating the game when I get new broadband internet and seeing what happens then.

Comment: Are there actually two different people in the room? The One uses the Kinect to automatically assign controllers. Hence, if you set down "your" controller and pick up the second one, it becomes "yours". If you have a Kinect, try unplugging it or covering it up so it won't recognize which controller you hold.

Comment: actually, the one can function without the kinect, and you only need two controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in a menu it will not let a second controller(or third or fourth) join, but for me, I just need to back out to the main screen, press start, and then add the controllers on the first screen, or the one that follows the main menu.